# Better way of serving assets to a react project?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, assets

My web application has lots of static images(say 100s) to be rendered in the UI.
note that not all images are to be shown on a single page together, instead, those are shown conditionally i.e only 3-5 images are displayed actually in the whole UI.

I want to know does having too many assets affects the production build?

Answer (score 1):

You should upload images to S3, keep the access of these images as public.

If your application is popular you should consider setting up [cloud-front](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in front of s3.

Comment: I wanted to know if this brings any extra benefits?

Comment: your server wont have to deal with download of files. hence responsiveness of your site will increase.